# How can i change the text color of colormap caption in python foluim?

Tags: python, colormap

I use foluim to create the gis map with Python.

the default text color of colormap caption in foluim is black. if i set the white background map,  it visible.

[image]

But, if i set the black background map, i cannot see the text any more.   my question is how can i change the text color of colormap caption? such as i want to change to red color.

[image]